# Not able to open a link directly in vscode (Windows 11)

Tags: visual-studio, url, hyperlink, localhost, flask-restful

I am not able to open the link by just clicking it and it is not showing follow link it showing me
handle link. By this issue I am giving manually to see the output in a browser. How to solve this handle link issue [this is how I am getting the link I am not able to copy the link or open the link by clicking it.] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mS7f.png)

i am expecting anyone know about this issue please give me solution.

Comment: As it says, you should ctrl+click, not just click.

Comment: i clicked with ctl  only but not able to open the link